# Rails string parse for forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parsing

How do I parse out a string in rails? I have my form for submitting a height. Example: 5'9 I want the comma parsed and the 59 saved within the database

Comment: Could you provide more info? Do you only ever want numbers saved into that field, or do you want to allow some punctation like periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore anything other than numbers, use this regex

```
 "5'9".gsub(/\D/, '')
 # => "59"
 "5 9".gsub(/\D/, '')
 # => "59" 
 "5 feet 9 inches".gsub(/\D/, '')
 # => "59" 
 '5"  9'.gsub(/\D/, '')
 # => "59"
```

Regex Explanation: `\D` stands for any character other than a digit.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. If you want to just remove the quote, you could use:

```
"5'9".gsub "'", ""
#=> "59"
```

or

```
"5'9".split("'").join("")
#=> "59"
```

If you want to save the 5 and the 9 in different attributes, you could try:

```
a = "5'9".split("'")
object.feet = a[0]
object.inches = a[1]
```

If you want to remove everything but the numbers you could use a regex:

```
"5'9".gsub /[^\d]/, ""
#=> "59"
```

If you have a different requirement, please update the question to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the [sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-sub) or [gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) methods

```
height.gsub! "'", ''
```

Where `sub` replaces the *first* instance, and `gsub` replaces *all* instances and you could even do this on the model:

```
before_validation :remove_apostrophes # or before_save

protected
def remove_apostrophes
  self.property.gsub! "'", ''
end
```